# How can I make $lookup embed the document directly instead of wrapping it into array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d779541bd4e75c58d598212")
    "client": ObjectId("5d779558bd4e75c58d598213")
}
```

When I do `$lookup` like this:

```
{
    from: 'client',
    localField: 'client',
    foreignField: 'id',
    as: 'client',
}
```

I get:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d779541bd4e75c58d598212")
    "client":[
        {
             ... client info wrapped in array
        }
     ]
}
```

This forces me to add `$unwind` after the lookup stage.

This would work fine in this example because I know that it is a regular field (not array). But on other collections I have arrays of `ObjectId's` and I don't want to `unwind` them.

**How should I tell `mongo` to unwind only if it's not an array?**

Comment: Why do you want to return a field with array or object. It must be either of one.

Comment: I want Mongo to keep the same "shape" of my data:
when I have {client:ObjectId("...")} I expect to receive either `null` when the `client` could not be found, or directly `{client: {all the client fields}}`
But if my original field was `{clients: [ObjectId(..), ObjectId(..)]}` then I expect it to return `{clients: [{...}, {...}]}`

Basically I want the same behavior as `mongoose.populate` but in the mongo server side

Comment: No sure why you are suppose to do that but you can do this way `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      collection: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$collection"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$collection",
              0
            ]
          },
          "$collection"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])`  https://mongoplayground.net/p/nqoq1RC7poj

Comment: @Ashh could be useful but it still causes a problem if the original ("to-be populated" field) was initially an array (which happens to be of length 1) because now if we try to populate it and use that snippet, it will turn it into a regular object
Basically I want mongo to do this: if original non-array, keep it non-array. if it is an array return as array

Comment: Then unfortunately it is not possible because `$lookup` does not return rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Add [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) stage with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
{ $lookup ..... },  
{ $project: { client: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$client" , 0 ]}} // Add other filed
```

Comment: It it still the same problem. I have to know if the field I "populated" was initially a regular field or an array. Because if I use this same query on an array it will only return the first "populated" item.

Comment: only one question what is your schema type clientId: ObjectId() or clientId: [ ObjectId(), ObjectId(),,,,,] ?

Answer (score 0):

The lookup always returns an array as it doesn't know if its a one-to-one or one-to-many mapping. But we can ensure that the lookup returns a single document and that document would hold all documents which were supposed to come as an array in the general lookup.

**Following is the way:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"client",
            "let":{
                "client":"$client"
            },
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $match:{
                        $expr:{
                            $eq:["$id","$$client"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "data":{
                            $push:"$$ROOT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        "_id":0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"clientLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$clientLookup"
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Query analysis:** We are looking up into `client` collection and executing a pipeline inside that. The output of that pipeline would hold every matched document inside `data` field.

## **Data set:**

**Collection:** collection

```
{
    "client":1
}
{
    "client":2
}
```

**Collection:** client

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Tony"
}
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Thor"
}
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Natasha"
}
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Banner"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7792c6bd4e75c58d59820c"),
    "client" : 1,
    "clientLookup" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d779322bd4e75c58d59820e"),
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "Tony"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d779322bd4e75c58d59820f"),
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "Thor"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d779322bd4e75c58d598210"),
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "Natasha"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7792c6bd4e75c58d59820d"),
    "client" : 2,
    "clientLookup" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d779322bd4e75c58d598211"),
                "id" : 2,
                "name" : "Banner"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```